# dingo api validator rule need to fix

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

```
public function store(Request $request) {

        $response = array('response' => '', 'success'=>false);

        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];

        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if($validator->fails()){
            $response['response'] = $validator->messages();
            return $this->response->error($response, 401);
            // or
            return $this->response->error($validator, 401);

        }else{
            User::create($request->all());  
        }

    }
```

How can I set validator in laravel using dingo API? I tried above code but does not work can't understand where is the right reference to keep track error logs

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rules = [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];

    $payload = app('request')->only('username', 'password');

    $validator = app('validator')->make($payload, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        throw new Dingo\Api\Exception\StoreResourceFailedException('Invalid username provided.', $validator->errors());
    }
```

You can try this

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store() 
{
     $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];


    $payload = app('request')->only('username', 'password');

    $validator = app('validator')->make($payload, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        throw new Dingo\Api\Exception\StoreResourceFailedException('Could not create new user.', $validator->errors());
    }

    User::create($request->all());

    // send a success response
}
```

This example is taken from the [documentation of Dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Errors-And-Error-Responses#resource-exceptions) and customized based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do validation especially when using Dingo API is to use [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests).

When using Dingo API however, you use

```
use Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest;
```

instead of

`use App\Http\Requests\Request;`
like in normal form requests.

So in your case, you'd have a form request like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateUser extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

So this keeps validations outside your controller. And your controller function can just be

```
public function store(Request $request) {
      User::create($request->all());  
}
```

If you are not very familiar with [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests), this is a great chance to look at it. Cheers.